# I am trying to get values from specific columns

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have try to get values from specific columns from google sheet and for loop to find matching between column title name and row names so if user click on a button that have info about a movie all name of the cast in that movie will appear in a table, The code I have does that right , but there are columns that contain people's names that I don't want to show Is there a way to get the data with the same code that I have, but with specific columns that get all the data from?

My code

```
function getSecondData(moveId){
  if(moveId == undefined)
    moveId = 14;
  var secondSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(ss2);
  var secondSh = secondSS.getSheetByName('Moves');
  var Data = secondSh.getDataRange().getValues();
  var actorName= secondSh.getRange(1,5,1,secondSh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  Data.splice(0,1);
  var tmpData = [];
  for(var x=0 ; x<Data.length ; x++){
    if(Data[x][3] == moveId){
      tmpData.push(Data[x]);
    }
  }
  var finalData = [];
  for(var x=0 ; x<tmpData.length ; x++){
    for(var y=4 ; y<tmpData[x].length ; y++){
      if(tmpData[x][y] != ''){
       finalData[y-3] = tmpData[x][y]+'^'+tmpData[x][0];
       }
    }
  }
  return {'data':finalData,'move':moveId,'files':actorName}
}
```

I have tried `getRangeList()` but dose not give you the value and you cant use `push()` on it

Because it is not possible to explain the whole process in detail, I designed it on Figma https://www.figma.com/file/8s69QPKmWIHLrlKuDz6NyH/

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question from your script and `['D1:1000', 'I1:I1000', 'M1:M1000', 'T1:T1000'] Instead of the value of 1000 I would like to get up to the last data in this column`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? For example, which variable the value of `['D1:1000', 'I1:I1000', 'M1:M1000', 'T1:T1000']` is included in?

Comment: I added more explanation, I hope it is a little more clearer

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between your question from your script and `['D1:1000', 'I1:I1000', 'M1:M1000', 'T1:T1000'] Instead of the value of 1000 I would like to get up to the last data in this column` and your additional image. Your image is the sample input situation? If it's so, can you provide the sample output situations you expect? By this, I would like to try to understand your question.

Comment: I have set the outputs, If this can be achieved please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. In your goal, you want to show the columns "A", "D" and "F" and you want to hide all other columns. Is my understanding correct? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the relationship between your images and your script. I apologize for this.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to do

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `This is exactly what I'm trying to do`, I understood that you want to show the columns "A", "D" and "F" and you want to hide all other columns. About this, I posted the sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your goal, I apologize.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. When I confirmed my understanding of your question like `In your goal, you want to show the columns "A", "D" and "F" and you want to hide all other columns. Is my understanding correct?`, you said `This is exactly what I'm trying to do`. So I proposed an answer for it.

Comment: But, from your replying of `Some time words and images are not not enough please see the this link to have more info` and an image, it seems that my understanding was not correct. So I have to delete my answer. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this again. Unfortunately, from your replying, I cannot understand what you want to do. Can I ask you about the detail of what you want to do? In your goal, you want to show the columns "A", "D" and "F" and you want to hide all other columns. How is my understanding not correct?

Comment: Your understanding is correct, but by hiding them, I mean not fetched from the database so that a html table can be created with the data gets from the database so with link I give you, you can see all the process

My English is also not good so don't let that bother you

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill. From your replying, I proposed 2 sample scripts in my answer. One is that only the columns "A", "D" and "F" are shown. Another is that the values of only the columns "A", "D" and "F" are retrieved. From your replying, I thought that 2nd one might be matched. But in your previous replying, you said `Some time words and images are not not enough`. So I'm confused about your goal. I deeply apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: Please check figma I have added more information
https://www.figma.com/file/8s69QPKmWIHLrlKuDz6NyH/

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I thought that you might want to retrieve the values from the specific columns. But, in my 2nd proposed script, the values are retrieved from the specific columns. So, can I ask you about your current issue for my 2nd proposed script? For example, can you provide the sample output values you expect for the function `getSecondData`? By this, I would like to try to understand your question. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: I made a video explaining more, watch it on YouTube https://youtu.be/eZf30ktWkjM

Comment: Thank you for repliyng. From your replying, I understood that "Google sheet1" and "Google sheet2" are the sample input sheets. If my understanding is correct, where can I see the sample output situation using your sample input sheets?

Comment: Google sheet1 Output is Table 1
Google sheet2 Output is Table 2 if you click see more

Comment: Thank you for replying. You want to convert from "Google sheet1" to "Google sheet2". Is my understanding correct?